# Write to a div in a new window

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page,  X.html:

```
......
<div id = "content"></div>
......
```

I use following code to open the X.html and want to write something in the content div.

```
content = "show in the div in the new window";
newWindow = window.open('X.html','');
newWindow.document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = content;
```

This doesn't work. 
I used Firebug, the code ends after the new window pops out. I don't want to write the whole thing in X.html and I want to use this simple way to write content in a specific area in the X.html.

What should I do?

Comment: try `newWindow.getElementById("content").innerHTML = content;`

Comment: try newWindow.document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = content;

Answer (score 0):

I believe that will help you.

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/writingt.htm

Comment: Like what I said, I can write the page using this way. What I want is to write content to a specific area in a existing page, not to create a whole new page.